# node:events:505 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event code: 'ECONNRESET'

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create a Newsletter with the help of mailchimp API.Down below you find the necessary code that I wrote to make a signup.
When I fill in the form and press submit an error occurs.

the signup.html file contains a simple form with 3 inputs(first name, surname and an email) and a submit button.
this is my app.js code:

```html
  

    const express = require("express");
    const request = require("request");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const app = express();
    const https = require("https");

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static("public"));

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
    });

    app.post("/", function (req, res) {
      const fname = req.body.firstName;
      const sname = req.body.lastName;
      const e_mail = req.body.Email;
      const data = {
        members: [
          {
            email_address: e_mail,
            status: "subscribed",
            merge_fields: [
              {
                FNAME: fname,
                LNAME: sname,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };

      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
      const url = "https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}";
      const options = {
        method: "POST",

        auth: "hamza:{API_id}",
      };
      https.request(url, options, function (response) {
        const request = response.on("data", function (data) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
        request.write(jsonData);
        request.end();
      });
    });

    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log("working successfully");
    });
```

This is the error I got

```html
  

  node:events:505
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: socket hang up
        at connResetException (node:internal/errors:692:14)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:478:23)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
        at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:478:9)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
      code: 'ECONNRESET'
    }
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've written this line

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

You should write your `res.sendFile` as

```
res.sendFile(signup.html);
```

Your `const data` should be written as

```
const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: firstName,
                    LNAME: lastName
                }
            }
            
        ]
    }
```

There is no need for the extra comma in your `const option`, right after the `auth`:

Your `https request` should be written as

```
 const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
        response.on('data', function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data))
        })
    })
```

I hope this helps

PS: Also be sure the `name` in your `input` tag from the `form` in your `signup.html` is correctly written.